# Moq a fake cookie in Asp.Net MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, moq

This is my Action for my Login Controller. I am able to mock the action using Moq.
But i get an error when it hits **this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("AcceptedDoDNotice") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });**

***Error:Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

How do i Mock the cookie so i wont get the error above?

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = _uow.UserRepository.FindLogin(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                _uow.UserRepository.UpdateLastLoginDate(user);                    
                _uow.SaveChanges();

                this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("MyCookie") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });

                if (user.UserLevel.IsAdmin)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator");

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }


        return View(model);
}
```

The Moq test is below:
            //Arrange
            var model = new LoginViewModel();
            model.Email = realEmail;
            model.Password = realPassword;

```
        //Act
        var loginController = new LoginController();
        var result = loginController.Login(model) as RedirectToRouteResult;
        var actual = result.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be("Administrator");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to mock the controller context. This will allow you to provide a mocked response which in turn provides a cookie collection that you control. You can then see exactly which cookies were set on the response.

```
var cookieCollection = new HttpCookieCollection { };
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
response.SetupGet(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookieCollection);

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

var loginController = new LoginController();
loginController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), loginController);

var model = new LoginModel { };
var result = loginController.Login(model) as RedirectToRouteResult;
var actual = result.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();

//Assert
actual.Should().Be("Administrator");
cookieCollection.Should().HaveCount(1);

// other assertions about your cookie
```